# A problem about SQNR, PCM, DPCM, and DM

Tags: sampling, nyquist, pcm, dpcm

> A baseband analog message signal $x(t)$ with bandwidth 20 kHz, power
> $10^{-3}$, and $|x(t)| \leq 1$ is waveform encoded and transmitted
> through a channel of bandwidth 160 kHz. Besides, let the sampled data
> of $x(t)$ be denoted by $x_n$ and suppose that $$ | x_n - x_{n-1}|
> > \leq 10^{-0.55 f_s / f_N}, $$ where $f_s$ denotes the sampling rate
> and $f_N$ denotes the Nyquist rate, for all $n$ when $f_s \geq f_N$.
> If we require SQNR $\geq$ 30 dB, please answer the followng questions.
>
> (a) Determine the maximum bit rate, $R_{b\_max}$, of the coded binary
> data.
>
> (b) If PCM was used for encoding, determine the range of bits,
> $v_{PCM}$, can be so that SQNR required is fullfilled.
>
> (c) If DPCM was used for encoding, determine the range of bits,
> $v_{DPCM}$, can be so that SQNR required is fulfilled according to
> $R_{b\_max}$ determined in (a).
>
> (d) Determine the condition of $f_s$ so that DM could fulfill the SQNR
> required according to $R_{b\_max}$ determined in (a).
>
> (e) According to the above results, determine which encoding
> method(s), among PCM, DPCM, and DM, can be suitable to transmit
> through the channel.

---

The following is my attempt to solve the above questions:

(a) According to the Shannon capacity formula, the maximum bit rate is the channel capacity:
$$R_{b_\max} = C = W \log_2 (1 + SQNR) = 160 \times 10^3 \times \log_2(1 + 10^{30/10}) \approx 1.5948 \times 10^6 \text{ bits/s}.$$

(b) From Eq. (7.4.4) in [1] we know that
$$\left. \text{SQNR} \right|_{\text{dB}} \approx 10 \log_{10} \frac{P_X}{x^2_{\max}} + 6 v_{PCM} + 4.8,$$
where $P_X$ is the power in each sample and $x_{\max}$ is the maximum possible value for $x(t)$. Now $P_X = 10^{-3}$ and $x_{\max} = 1$, so
$$ 10 \log_{10} \frac{10^{-3}}{1^2} + 6 v_{PCM} + 4.8 \geq 30.$$
Solving the above equation, we get
$$ v_{PCM} \geq \frac{46}{5} = 9.2 \text{ bits}.$$
Because the number of bits must be a positive integer, the range of bits is
$$v_{PCM} \geq 10 \text{ bits}.$$

(c) The Nyquist rate is
$$ f_N = 2 \times 20 \text{ kHz} = 40 \text{ kHz}.$$
According to Example 7.4.2 in [1], for DPCM, the bit rate is
$$ R = v_{DPCM} f_s \geq v_{DPCM} f_N = v_{DPCM} \times 40 \text{ kHz}. $$
On the other hand,
$$ R \leq R_{b\_max}. $$
Therefore,
$$ v_{DPCM} \times 40 \text{ kHz} \leq 1.5948 \times 10^6 \text{ bits/s}. $$
Then
$$ v_{DPCM} \leq \frac{1.5948 \times 10^6}{40 \times 10^3} = 39.87 \text{ bits}. $$
Again, the number of bits must be a positive integer. So
$$ v_{DPCM} \leq 39 \text{ bits}. $$

(d) In DM only one bit per sample is employed, so
$$ f_s = R \leq R_{b\_max}.$$
This implies that
$$ f_s \leq 1.5948 \times 10^6 \text{ Hz} = 159.48 \text{ kHz}.$$
On the other hand,
$$ f_s \geq f_N = 40 \text{ kHz}. $$
So
$$ 40 \text{ kHz} \leq f_s \leq 159.48 \text{ kHz}.$$

(e) I think PCM, DPCM, and DM can be all suitable to transmit through the channel. But I am not so sure. $\blacksquare$

**Reference:**

[1] J. G. Proakis and M. Salehi, *Fundamentals of Communication Systems*, Second Edition, Pearson, 2014.

Comment: OK, I will try to show my work. Thank you for your comment.